# How to use a custom template file to export data

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I am trying to work out the best way to export data from a WPF application using custom template files, but despite hours of searching have drawn a blank.

**The scenario is as follows:**

We have a WPF MVVM application for internal company use and one of the Views is for generating invoices. There is an option to Export to a Word document on this View which is currently implemented with various hard coded string literals in the ViewModel, far from ideal.

The current setup does work, but doesn't feel right to me and I'd like to improve it. We also have a new requirement to add different types of invoice, so I'm taking this opportunity to tidy things up.

The export process currently involves creating an HTML document as a string and then inserting this into a Word document. There may be better ways of doing this, but that is out of the scope of this question, the same question would apply if the final output required was HTML. To keep things simple, let's just say that we're interested in any type of export file that can be represented as a string and with no dynamic layout such as multiple rows of data i.e. we're just doing a find/replace on the string.

**What I would like to do:**

- Create custom template files containing placeholders
- Specify in the View which template(s) to use
- Inject data into the template(s) using data in the ViewModel

Is this the right way to be going about this? If not, what would be a better alternative?

Where should the template file(s) be stored? I have assumed they would be resources in the WPF application.

Where should the template manipulation / data injection be done? I initially assumed a string would be loaded into the ViewModel and this would do the manipulation, but maybe there is some better way of manipulating the data in the View.

After all that, let's get on with the actual question!

**The question:**

For any given export file type that can be represented as a string, what is the best way to store a template in WPF MVVM and inject data into it?

Comment: Have you thought about XML ?

Comment: @Aybe do you mean use an XML file to store the different template files in a structured way? That's a possibility, but the same issue would remain of how can I access this XML file in the ViewModel if it is part of the View?

Answer (score 0):

After trying and failing to pass the file data from the View to the ViewModel I ended up passing the file path instead. This path is then used by the ViewModel to load the template and inject the data. It's not quite what I was originally aiming for but does work and has the advantage of being able to specify the file path in the View thereby keeping it out of the ViewModel.

I'm also using a .docx file as a template rather than .html due to issues with Word displaying the embedded image. This template file is included in the WPF project with a Build Action of Content.

View XAML:

```
<Label Content="{Binding Path=InvoiceTemplateFile, FallbackValue='\\Templates\\Invoice\\InvoiceTemplate.docx', Mode=OneWayToSource}" Visibility="Collapsed" />
```

ViewModel property:

```
    private string _invoiceTemplateFile;
    public string InvoiceTemplateFile
    {
        get { return _invoiceTemplateFile; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _invoiceTemplateFile)
                return;

            _invoiceTemplateFile = value;

            base.OnPropertyChanged("InvoiceTemplateFile");
        }
    }
```

Accessing the file path in the ViewModel:

```
string templateFilePath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, this.InvoiceTemplateFile);
```

I'm open to any better suggestions!